# Help find this limit

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the limit below

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+2y^2}$$

I know that the limit must be zero if it exists since coming along the line $y=mx$ for an constant $m$  gives $0$, but I don't know how to prove it. I want to use [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) but I don't know what function to use for it.

Comment: Show it separately for $x^3/(x^2+2y^2)$ and $2y^3/(x^2+2y^2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach with ellipses $x=r \cos (\theta)$ and $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}r \sin (\theta)$ with $r \to 0^+$ regardless of $\theta$.

This gives,

$$\lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{r^3 \cos^3(\theta)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}r^3 \sin^3 (\theta)}{r^2}$$

$$=\lim_{r \to 0^+} r(\cos^3 (\theta)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin^3 (\theta))$$

$$=0$$

Or note,

$$|\frac{x^3}{x^2+2y^2}| \leq |\frac{x^3}{x^2}|$$

$$=|x| \to 0$$

Similarly we have,

$$|\frac{-2y^3}{x^2+2y^2 }| \leq |\frac{2y^3}{2y^2}|$$

$$=|y| \to 0$$

Now use $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$ to conclude with squeeze.

Answer (score 3):

You can see that, for all $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ :

$$\frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+2y^2}=\frac{x^3}{x^2+2y^2}-2\frac{y^3}{x^2+2y^2}$$

so, by triangular inequality :

$$\left|\frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+2y^2}\right|\le\frac{\vert x\vert^3}{x^2+y^2}+2\frac{\vert y\vert^3}{x^2+y^2}\le\vert x\vert+2\vert y\vert\le2(\vert x\vert+\vert y\vert)$$

It is now clear that the desired limit is $0$.